# Is x==x ever False in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, equality

I stumbled upon this line of code in SciPy's source, in the [stats module](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/distributions.py#L5171):

```
return 1.0*(x==x)
```

Is this return something other than `1.0`? In other words, is there any value of x such that `x == x` holds `False`?

Comment: What is `x` in this instance?  Does it implement the `__eq__` method?  Does it's return for that method result in something unexpected?  More context is probably necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer should I accept as correct, because a) Both the answer about `NaN` and overriding the `__eq__` method have their point and b) I realised *why* is this code there: *it is meant to return an array full of ones of the same size as `x`*.

Comment: @NeilG tell the SciPy developers...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the IEEE 754 standard not-a-number (NaN) must always compare false, no matter what it is compared to.

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=float("NaN")
>>> x==x
False
```

Comment: You are right, indeed: 

    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> np.nan == np.nan
    False

Answer (score 9):

A user-defined type can override the equality operator to do whatever you want:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Feb 10 2012, 09:23:17) 
[GCC 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
... 
>>> x=A()
>>> x==x
False
```

Answer (score 3):

that depends on the value of x. I haven't looked at the source, but let's say you do something like this:

```
class A:
 def __eq__(self,other):
  return bool(random.getrandbits(1))

x = A()
```

now `x == x` may return false.